# System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' in c#

Tags: c#

Hello everyone I'm beginner at programming , and I saw this error in my program  and I don't understand what I do.

```cs
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    double a = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
    double num = a*10;           
    MessageBox.Show(num.ToString());
}
```

Comment: if you enter numbers using dot as separator, for example `12.34`, then can write `Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: Well, `textBox1.Text` value *doesn't represent* any valid `double`; `textBox1.Text` can be, say `"bla-bla-bla"` or an empty string. Please, check `textBox1.Text` value

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out var a) ? $"{a * 10}" : $"\"{textBox1.Text}\" is not a valid value");`

Comment: What exactly did you type in the textbox?

Comment: I typed 10.25 . I got my answer .thank u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that your text in a text box can't be converted into double. Maybe there is a some non numeric string value or some characters which are not relevant for double values.

First of all you should check your string if it is really numeric value and if text could not be parsed as double show appropriate message:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    var txt = textBox1.Text;
    double a;
    if(!double.TryParse(txt, out a)
    {
          MessageBox.Show("Enter Valid Double Value");
          return;
    }
    double num = a*10;           
    MessageBox.Show(num.ToString());
}
```